# API to query AWS User Documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

Is there an API/way to programmatically query AWS documentation for a specific service? For instance, I want to know the encryption algorithm used by a service for protecting data at rest. Can I write a script that will automatically query AWS documentation for that service and give me this information?

Comment: There is no such API.

Answer (score 3):

There is no API for AWS Documentation.

However, the AWS CLI is open-source and it has data files that detail all API calls and their parameters.

It would not, however, contain the encryption algorithms. That is internal to Amazon S3 and is not shared publicly.